# How to pass a data frame as parameter to a SQL query in Python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of one column of values and I want to pass it as a parameter to execute the following sql query:

```
query = "SELECT ValueDate, Value"\
        "FROM Table "\
        "WHERE [ID] in ( ? ) "
```

So I tried (among so many other things) the following:

```
      df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=[ df['ID'].values ])
      df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=[ df['ID'].tolist ])
      df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=[ list(df['ID'].values) ])
       ...
```

What is the correct way to pass the dataframe values ?

NB: I am using Microsoft SQL Server so the query needs to be formatted as I did.

Comment: Now that you have specified sql-server, table valued parameters might be the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this get you what you need?

```
import pandas as pd

your_column = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

query = "SELECT ValueDate, Value"\
        "FROM Table "\
        "WHERE [ID] in {}".format(tuple(your_column))

print(query)
# 'SELECT ValueDate, ValueFROM Table WHERE [ID] in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)'
```

Then you should be able to query without further parameters.

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

Comment: This will work only if your column has more than one rows. If it has only one row, converting it into a tuple will result in SQL error. Query will look like " .... where [ID] in (1,) ". As you are converting the result into a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
params = tuple(df['ID'].values)
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foobar WHERE id IN (%s)" % (",".join(["?"]*len(params)),)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Thank you but I forgot to say that I am using Microsoft SQL Server, so the query needs to be formatted as in my question.

Comment: Consider adding a description of how the code you've posted works, it will be helpful to users that visit this post in the future.