# How to use a list/array of values as column name in select statement?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, oracle

Say I have 3 list of data that I am using to build a new query. I need to take these list of data and return the values of those list where things were found.

So my question is this:

> Is there a standard method of taking a list and using it as a column?

I will need to use multiple list as columns where one column is the "JOIN ON" or "WHERE IN" portion.

The results from my first query are used to build my 3 list.

Say I get back this data:

```
[[ID, TYPE, OTHER],
 [1, C, S], 
 [2, C, O],
 [3, D, D],
 [4, D, H]]
```

Then convert that table/2D Array to the following Python List:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[C, C, D, D]
[S, O, D, H]
```

Now I want to use those 2 list as columns in a select statement like this:

```
select [C, C, D, D] as TYPE # These 2 list are needed to return in the correct order
      ,[S, O, D, H] as OTHER  # as it relates to [1, 2, 3, 4] in the WHERE.
      ,table.value
      ,table.color
From table
where table.value in [1, 2, 3, 4]  # one list is used to deal with the where
```

`table` contains 2 columns:

```
VALUE    COLOR
1        Red
2        Green
3        Blue
4        Black
```

Results should look like this:

```
TYPE    OTHER    VALUE    COLOR
C       S        1        Red
C       O        2        Green
D       D        3        Blue
D       H        4        Black
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: @jarlh both. Some of my queries will be directly on the SQL Server and some will be using `OPENQUERY` against a linked Oracle server. I can get data with single values as columns but I need to be able to do this with a list of values. Otherwise I will have to build 20 Union statements and I really don't think that is efficient.

Comment: Not sure how you would do this in python but what you are describing is a table valued parameter in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange this has to be pass in a query string that is sent to the SQL Server via pyodbc using the ODBC standard drivers. Again I can do this with single values just not lists.

Comment: Well as you have found out you can't pass arrays of values in a standard string. And you have a two dimensional array at that. You can use a string splitter and pass in delimited lists. But you are going to need one that returns the ordinal position of each element so you can reassemble a delimited list and get the values lined up correctly. Here is a great example of one of those. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2

Comment: @SeanLange hum. That is a bit more complicated than I will be able to implement any time soon. I guess for now I will write UNIONS until I can figure out how to implement what you have linked.

Comment: Yeah I hear you there. But what you are trying to do is pass an entire table with nothing but a string. This is sort of like passing a single tab of data from excel in a string. It is complicated because that is not a good way of sending that information. If I understood what you are trying to do more clearly I could maybe offer some better alternatives.

Comment: Ya. This is very similar to taking the data stored in excel, converting it into Python lists and then using those list to build the select statement. Its not a problem when I only need to use one column of data from excel in a `WHERE IN` statement but when I also want to take several other columns as data in the returned table is where I am getting stuck. I could likely do some extra work to match rows in one tab of excel and then copy that data over to the new tab that holds the query results. Its a work around at least but it would have been so much nicer to simple use a list in the select.

Comment: @SeanLange can you take a 2D Array and send it to the server as a table to be used in the `FROM/JOIN`? Like inside the sql string. One problem is I cannot create temp tables as this application will be used by many people at one time. So constant creation and deletion of temp tables is not a great idea. I wonder if something like PANDA's can be used as a table in a query against a server?

Comment: Something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354292/how-to-pass-a-data-frame-as-parameter-to-a-sql-query-in-python/43354606

Comment: @SeanLange that is what I am currently doing. That works for only needing one list of data to work with but when I need multiple list to be returned in the select itself that is my issue. I have however finished the code to write multiple UNIONS for now until I can get around to your first link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is the solution I have to go with.

Instead of managing the data on the client side I will create a new database on the SQL Server and then all the needed tables the tool will interact with.

Then I will have the program insert and delete rows in each table based on the user who is using the tool.

Getting the username is simple as:

```
import os

print(os.getlogin())
```

As there will 99% of the time be less than 100 rows being added and deleted for any of the say 10 users at a time this will be efficient enough to handle the work.

This solutions is far more efficient then my current `UNION` method and will also allow each user to only see and work with data related to their login.

Seeing that each table will likely never exceed a total of 10,000 rows I don't think this will be much of an issue even without having a primary key to work with.

Answer (score 0):

***Update:***

1, Convert the table into 3 lists:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas

db = cx_Oracle.connect('*******', '********', '*******')
conn = db.cursor()

sql_test = '''SELECT * FROM TEST'''

sql_table = '''SELECT * FROM "TABLE" '''

df_test = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_test,db)
df_table = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_table,db)

ser_aggCol=df_test.aggregate(lambda x: [x.tolist()], axis=0).map(lambda x:x[0])

print(ser_aggCol, sep='\n', end='\n\n\n')

print(ser_aggCol['ID'])
print(ser_aggCol['TYPE'])
print(ser_aggCol['OTHER'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

2, Use while loop to concat the dataframe row by row.

```
sql_max = '''SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TEST'''
conn.execute(sql_max)
max_id = 0
for result in conn:
    max_id = result[0]

print(max_id)

i = 0
sql_first_row = '''select \'''' + ser_aggCol['TYPE'][i] + '''\' as TYPE, \'''' + ser_aggCol['OTHER'][i] + '''\' AS OTHER, VALUE, COLOR FROM "TABLE" WHERE VALUE = '''+ str(ser_aggCol['ID'][i])
df_result = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_first_row,db)

while i + 1 <= max_id - 1:
    new_sql = '''select \'''' + ser_aggCol['TYPE'][i+1] + '''\' as TYPE, \'''' + ser_aggCol['OTHER'][i+1] + '''\' AS OTHER, VALUE, COLOR FROM "TABLE" WHERE VALUE = '''+ str(ser_aggCol['ID'][i+1])
    df_new = pandas.read_sql_query(new_sql, db)
    df_result = pandas.concat([df_result,df_new])
    i = i + 1

print(df_result)
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Original Post:**

My approach is:

1, Read the SQL results into the dataframes

```
pandas.read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize=None)
```

2, Join the dataframes using Pandas

```
DataFrame.join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)
```

---

---

Testing:

I do not have the SQL Server client on my new PC so I created those two tables in Oracle only. You just need to add the SQL Server connection in your Python.
Let me know if you got stuck here.

***Created two tables in Oracle:***

**Test:**

[image]

**Table:**

[image]

**Then Python:**

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas

db = cx_Oracle.connect('********', '********', '********')
conn = db.cursor()

sql_test = '''SELECT * FROM TEST'''

sql_table = '''SELECT * FROM "TABLE" '''

df_test = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_test,db)
df_table = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_table,db)

print(df_test) 
print(df_table)

print(df_test.set_index('ID').join(df_table.set_index('VALUE')))
```

Output:

```
   ID TYPE OTHER
0   1    C     S
1   2    C     O
2   3    D     D
3   4    D     H

   VALUE  COLOR
0      1    Red
1      2  Green
2      3   Blue
3      4  Black

ID  TYPE OTHER  COLOR                  
1     C     S    Red
2     C     O  Green
3     D     D   Blue
4     D     H  Black
```

Comment: I have updated my questions to provide some more context and how I plan to use the data. I will have to wait till I get back to work tomorrow to test the code against out server.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I just updated my answer. Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: That is interesting is `df_test.set_index('ID').join(df_table.set_index('VALUE'))` basically the same thing as `JOIN ON`?. My concern here is that it looks to be a full table scan between the 2 tables and that will be a hefty price on the spool space. Pulling down all the data will not work. I need to somehow send the column of say TEST as a select statement to the Oracle server so it is only pulling back values I need.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, Could you test it? As I know, pandas now has one of the fastest in-memory database join operators out there.

Comment: @Mike-SMT, Also, you can use DataFrame.where() after you joined the tables to pull the data you need.

Comment: Well your statement looks like it is pulling all the data from each table into memory. That is bad practice and very high on CPU cost. However when I get a chance I will test it to verify.