# Dynamically created Dataframe as SQL parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oracle, dataframe

I am trying to pull SQL data in python through the `read_sql_query()`.

To pull the data, i am using the below SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (:ids);
```

before these steps, the previous code generates a list of ids in the form of a dataframe. This dataframe can have only 1 id or more than 1000 ids as well.

After searching elsewhere, I can save the df in the form of tuples and then save the query as string with the tuples. I found this solution here:
[How to pass a data frame as parameter to a SQL query in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354292/how-to-pass-a-data-frame-as-parameter-to-a-sql-query-in-python)

But this only works if the df has less than 1000 records.

How to run this so as to include something like 1800 ids.

Answer (score 0):

The `read_sql_query()` function supports a `chunksize` argument.

You can use

```
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ids IN ({})".format(ids), engine, chunksize=100):
    print(chunk)
```

*default* value of chunksize is `None`. if a spesific value is provided, then pandas will be interaction with the database to receive some more rows for every iteration of the loop depending on the chunksize value.